# Jupyter kernel not starting

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

My Jupyter kernel moves between dead, starting, connected status but can’t run any cell. I am running the kernel on the cluster and everything worked fine. I can use ipython from the terminal. A similar thing happens in both Jupyter lab and notebook.

I have reinstalled ipython and tested it with iptest, reinstalled Jupyter also.

```
pip uninstall ipykernel ipython jupyter_client jupyter_core traitlets ipython_genutils -y
pip install ipykernel ipython jupyter_client jupyter_core traitlets ipython_genutils
```

Versions:
Jupyter core     : 4.5.0
Jupyter-notebook : 5.7.8
Qtconsole        : 4.4.3
Ipython          : 7.8.0
Ipykernel        : 5.1.0
Jupyter client   : 5.2.4
Jupyter lab      : 1.1.4

Here is the [log file](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=13W0pfPLD_cuwuexn8HtmT_hBgEEDqr_W&export=download) when running Jupyter lab.

Comment: I had the same issue some weeks ago but re-installing everything helped. But I did it multiple times..  my feeling is that this is due to some environmental variables but can't help specifically, unfortunately.

Comment: I ended up creating a new conda env and reinstalling everything.